# USB Type-C SMD connector PCB layout reference design

Tags: connector, datasheet, surface-mount, usb-c

I am designing a board with a USB 3.2 Type-C connector from [Molex](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/io_connectors/1054500101), and I understand that at a possible 10Gbps, this design is going to need to be very well laid out.

Is there somewhere a reference design showing one example of the PCB layout around such a connector?

According to the whitepaper [Managing Connector and Cable Assembly Performance for USB SuperSpeed](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB_SuperSpeed_CabCon_Whitepaper.pdf):

> System OEMs should get the optimized PCB launch designs from the connector manufacturer for their own PCB stack-ups.

Has anyone ever seen such a design from a connector manufacturer?

Comment: Have you contacted the connector manufacturer to see if they can provide optimized PCB launch designes for their connector? (also known as "Final Inch" designs).

Comment: @TomCarpenter - I haven't tried contacting them. I just assumed that if they were available, they'd be on the web site.

Comment: They don't aways provide information on the website. I've found Molex customer support quite responsive though. They may well have example designs or be able to provide pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Not a connector manufacturer, but TI does have some good tips that might help you here: https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/f/interface-forum/512449/type-c-connector-layout-made-easy